# Increase year of datetime array without using for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, datetime, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array which has a long list of datetimes. I was wondering is there a way to add a year to all values of the array at once without using a for loop? eg. Using some numpy or datetime module?

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import numpy as np

>>> dts.shape
(64580,)

>>> dts[:5]
array([datetime.date(2000, 1, 15), datetime.date(2000, 1, 15),
       datetime.date(2000, 1, 15), datetime.date(2000, 1, 15),
       datetime.date(2000, 1, 15)], dtype=object)

>>> new_dts = somemodule.somefunctionforaddingyearorsomething(dts, year=1)
>>> new_dts
array([datetime.date(2001, 1, 15), datetime.date(2001, 1, 15),
       datetime.date(2001, 1, 15), datetime.date(2001, 1, 15),
       datetime.date(2001, 1, 15)], dtype=object)
```

**Note:** Day of each date is always set to day 15 as the dates represent monthly mean data.

I have implemented it using a for loop however this can be computationally slow..

The code for that is here:

```
def add_year_to_Datelist(dl):

dts = dl.dates.copy()
for idx, date in enumerate(dts):
    dts[idx] = date.replace(year=date.year + 1)

dl.set_dates(dts)
return dl
```

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NumPy doesn't support "1 year" as a timedelta, since this can be 365 or 366 days. If you are willing to use Pandas, you can use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`pd.DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects), which *does* support year-based offsets:

```
import datetime, numpy as np, pandas as pd

dts = np.array([datetime.date(2000, 1, 15), datetime.date(2000, 1, 15),
                datetime.date(2000, 1, 15), datetime.date(2000, 1, 15),
                datetime.date(2000, 1, 15)], dtype=object)

dts = (pd.to_datetime(dts) + pd.DateOffset(years=1)).values.astype('datetime64[D]')

# array(['2001-01-15', '2001-01-15', '2001-01-15', '2001-01-15',
#        '2001-01-15'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

---

With NumPy, you *can* add a fixed number of days after converting your `object` dtype array to `np.datetime64`:

```
dts = dts.astype(np.datetime64) + np.timedelta64(365, 'D')

# array(['2001-01-14', '2001-01-14', '2001-01-14', '2001-01-14',
#        '2001-01-14'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

Note the 1-day mismatch between the two results.

Comment: Your pandas answer works perfectly! Although I tried the first answer and noticed that for any leap year the data will be incorrect. i.e months Jan/Feb have day value of 14 whereas the other months have day values of 15..

Comment: @MaxCollier, Yes, that's exactly the problem with using 365 days fixed. There's no native NumPy solution as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 2):

Making things faster while using a for loop is kind of hard. Using `map` however brings the calculations into C and can speed things up considerably.

Try this:

```
def add_year(dl, add=1):
    """Return new list with year increased by specified amount."""
    dts = list(map(lambda date: date.replace(year = date.year + add), dl.dates.copy()))
    return dts
```

Not sure how to get a numpy list because I haven't worked with numpy yet (I know, pathetic...) but you know so yeah :D